# Open Eclipse plugin view like a modal window

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have developed an eclipse RCP plugin, which is intended to run as an Eclipse application, and can be extracted as an standalone Eclipse product. Now, i want to reuse the same, by adding it as an plugin, so that i can be accessed from within eclipse.

I am able to install the same into my eclipse workspace and can see the view via *Window > Show View*. However the view opens into the area below the editor (along with Console view), instead of opening as a standalone window.

Please point me towards a way, by which the View opens in a separate window, just like the 'Search' window.

The view extends '*ViewPart*' and uses composites. 
Relevant bits from *Plugin.xml* below:

```
<extension id="application" point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run class="xxx.Application"></run>
      </application>
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective name="xxxReview.perspective" class="extension.Perspective" id="xxxReview.perspective">
      </perspective>
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <view class="view.xxxView" id="xxxView" name="xxxView" restorable="true">
      </view>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it work by extending SWT Dialog.

```
public class xxxView extends Dialog {

    /** The file Name Text field. */
    private Text fileNameText;

    /** The constructor. **/
    protected xxxView(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    /** Create Dialog View. **/
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {

        //Added View components here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own perspective defined, you can always override

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    layout.addStandaloneView(xxxView, false, IPageLayout.TOP, 0.04f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
    ...
}
```

If you need the view to be available in some of native Eclipse perspectives, try perspectiveExtensions with a standalone view

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views"> 
  <view class="view.xxxView" id="xxxView" name="xxxView" restorable="true" />
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
    <perspectiveExtension targetID="*">
        <view id="xxxView" visible="false" standalone="true"
            relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.ResourceNavigator" relationship="bottom" /> 
    </perspectiveExtension>
</extension>
```

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html

Comment: I already have defined the perspective as `layout.addStandaloneView("xxxView", false, IPageLayout.TOP, IPageLayout.RATIO_MAX, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);` . This make the view standalone, when opened as an application. However when opened directly as a view from within eclipse (after installing it as a plug-in), this opens in the parent eclipse window (editor/console area).